# using global-linum-mode with ess with a latex/R knit file

Tags: latex, ess, linum-mode

When using `global-linum-mode` with a latex file that has blocks of R code (`*.rnw` file) moving in and out of the R code blocks cause the line numbers to disappear until the cursor is moved again. Is there a way to stop the disappearing line numbers or just to turn off the line numbers for `*.rnw` files, but not in pure LaTeX ESS files?

Using 
`Aquamacs 3.2`
`GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2`
`ESS-Version 15.09-2`

Comment: Try setting the value of `linum-eager` to `t` in your init file to see if they update more reliably (this might slow things down though).

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem with ESS-Noweb and LaTeX mode. Are you using polymode? That would explain this, as when the cursor moves in and out of R chunks you are actually moving in and out of major modes while you do so. If this is the case, make sure linum-mode is enabled for .R source files, and they shouldn't disappear.

Comment: Thank you elethan for you advice, seems to have done the trick. Tyler thank you for trying to replicate.